# Angular2 - restore previous value on cancel in two-way data binding

Tags: angular, typescript

In two-way data binding what if user decides to cancel the current edits? How can this be achieved in angular 2?

Consider the following piece of code:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `Name: {{ name  }}<br>
    <input *ngIf='editMode' type="text" [(ngModel)]='name' /><br>
    <button *ngIf='!editMode' (click)='editMode = !editMode' >Edit</button>
    <button *ngIf='editMode' (click)='editMode = !editMode' >Save</button><br>
    <button *ngIf='editMode' (click)='editMode = !editMode' >Cancel</button>`
})
export class AppComponent {
  public name = 'Essa';
  public editMode false;
}
```

I want the old value to be restored when the user presses the cancel button.

Here is the [plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/IOw1vdxBMPDcuhlGKXAn/) as an example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think there is some direct support for this. Just store the value and restore it on cancel

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `Name: {{ name  }}<br>
    <input *ngIf='editMode' type="text" [(ngModel)]='name' /><br>
    <button *ngIf='!editMode' (click)='startEdit()' >Edit</button>
    <button *ngIf='editMode' (click)='save()' >Save</button><br>
    <button *ngIf='editMode' (click)='cancel()' >Cancel</button>`
})
export class AppComponent {
  public name = 'Essa';
  public editMode false;
  startEdit() {
    this.oldName = this.name;
    this.editMode = !this.editMode;
  }
  save() {
    this.editMode = !this.editMode;
  }
  cancel() {
    this.editMode = !this.editMode;
    this.name = this.oldName;
  }
}
```

The methods `startEdit`, `save` and `cancel` don't need to be added explicitely to the component. Bindings can contain more than one statement separated by `;` but I like this approach better if it's more than one statement.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/RMkYoUgY9ZAlEWbg6Slh?p=preview)

Comment: If I have one way data binding and I want to revert the input value to the one from the model how I can achieve this ?

Comment: Copy the values and re-assign the backup copies to the properties the inputs bind to.

Comment: Could you have a look at this one question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40423484/angular-2-refresh-ngmodel-on-the-view?noredirect=1#comment68095381_40423484 I also created a plunker