# Discard changes array Angular 2

Tags: data-binding, angular

Good morning,

I start playing with Ionic 2 and built my first list which can be editable using a modal.

In the modal, I have a save button and a cancel button.

Due to the data-binding and in order to discard my changes when the user hits the cancel button, I have followed this answer:
[Angular2 - restore previous value on cancel in two-way data binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36238097/angular2-restore-previous-value-on-cancel-in-two-data-binding).

```
onPageLoaded() {            
            this.BKPrecovery = this.recovery.tag_no;               
        }
    }

cancelRecovery() {      
        this.recovery.tag_no = this.BKPrecovery;
        this.dismiss();
    }
```

It works well but only for individual fields such as tag_no. In my case, I would like to revert to my initial array (recovery) before changes which contains multiple fields.

Is it possible to do so with Angular 2?

I saw that in Angular 1, you were able to do a deep copy of this objet but can not find it in Angular 2.

Thanks for your help.

Sylvain

Comment: show the data struct need restoring.